# Swift completion handler for network request causing SIGABRT

Tags: swift, networking

I'm using a completion handler to preform a network request, Once the network request is completed I add the result to a dictionary i've constructed that contains other information pertaining to the result. Then I call a function to change the text of the labels in my view controller. The code I'm using is:

```
    requestCalculateTotals(data["id"] as! String, pickupDate: data["pickup_date"] as! String, dropoffDate: data["dropoff_date"] as! String){
        (calculateData: NSDictionary) in
        self.data.addEntriesFromDictionary(calculateData as [NSObject : AnyObject])
        self.refreshDetails()
    }
```

This causes a SIGABRT error and I dont understand why? I've tested the completion handler and the network request and they both work, I can print the result data and it contains the data I expect. The refreshDetails function works outside of the completion handler but then it won't be waiting for the network request.

Is there something I've missed when constructing the completion handler or is there a there a better way I could wait for a network request?

**EDIT**  I get the error: "This application is modifying the autolayout engine from a background thread, which can lead to engine corruption and weird crashes.  This will cause an exception in a future release." How could I add my refreshDetails function in the main thread when the network request is complete?

Comment: SIGABRT is not the reason. You should check the stacktrace on debug window when app crashed and post it to your question.

Comment: Reset Simulator and restart Xcode may fix this issue.